# Will Object.observe provide a significant boost to Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, object.observe

Right now, Angular slows down after a few thousand objects, which prevents us from building something like a spreadsheet or Conway's Game of Life.

Once Object.observe is implement (in the far, far future), will these become possible with Angular? Or will DOM manipulation be the chokepoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes . checkout here 
https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-September/024978.html

Comment: Thank you for finding this. Interesting to know for the coming years.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in trying to solve a problem like this now, I recommend taking a look at this video from the AngularJS NYC Meetup from last year which talks about performance problems encountered while trying to implement similar scenarios.

[AngularJS NYC Meetup - dfa-stable-repeat and prototyping (2012-11-20)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8xkax9Z_sQ)